# Sort an NSArray by another nsarray with ids

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

i have 2 nsarrays
1 with nsdictionary's another with nsnumbers

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[@{@"id":@1},@{@"id":@2},@{@"id":@3},@{@"id":@4}];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@3,@1,@4,@2];
```

and i want to sort my arr1 through their id following the order of arr2
is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Simply write a function or method that accesses the second array and compares the appropriate values.  Then use sortUsingFunction/Selector.

Comment: Yes, encapsulate the data in a class and perform sort based on one of the properties. @HotLicks Hi, just curiosity, how would you do that with sortUsingFunction/Selector in code? Thanks.

Comment: That kind of sorting has a risk of `O(n^2)` time. I would put `arr1` into a hash map by `id` and then loop through `arr2` to map.  Assuming you know your ID's are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do it by using a custom comparator:

```
NSArray* sorted= [arr1 sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    return [arr2 indexOfObject:obj1[@"id"]] - [arr2 indexOfObject:[obj2[@"id"]];
}];
```

I exploited the fact that [NSComparisonResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult) has +1 to represent an ascending order, -1 for descending and 0 to represent the same order.

Comment: indexOfObject is brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` is you start dealing with `O(n^2)` lookup times.  For each sort comparison in the first array, you have to do a lookup in the second array.

Your best bet is to take advantage of a hash table to reduce that to `O(n)` average complexity.

Your first step is to create a dictionary using `id` as a key.  The result would look something like `@{@1: @{@"id":@"1"}, ...}`.  Then you just have to construct an array by looping through `arr3` and grabbing the values.

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[@{@"id":@1},@{@"id":@2},@{@"id":@3},@{@"id":@4}];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@3,@1,@4,@2];

NSMutableDictionary *map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *item in arr1) {
    map[item[@"id"]] = item;
}

NSMutableArray *arr3 = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id key in arr2) {
    [arr3 addObject:map[key]];
}
```

This solution of course assumes parity between the two arrays.  If `arr2` has an element not in `arr1` it will crash when trying to add `nil` to `arr3`.  If `arr1` has a value not in `arr2` it will be excluded from `arr3`.  These are risks you will have to address based on your requirements.

Comment: excuse me for asking question not being the OP, but what is @{}.mutableCopy? What would *map be after the assignment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a super lazy way of saying `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`.  It creates an empty `NSDictionary` and then creates a mutable version of it.  There's probably some level of performance hit but I feel like cases around an empty dictionary are well optimized for.

Comment: So, with these @{} and .mutableCopy it will become a NSMutableDictionary? Does that apply also to NSArray, for instance: NSMutableArray *array = @{}.mutableCopy; ?

Comment: You have to use `@[]` to create an array. `@{}` and `@[]` are syntactic sugar, described here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @BrianNickel `mutableCopy` is a method, not a property (even in the broadest sense of the term), so your example's usage of the dot operator isn't just lazy, it's wrong.

Comment: @jlehr I said it was *super* lazy. Using legal notation would have just been regular lazy.  Since the whole discussion is distracting from the original question, I'm editing to `[NSMutableLongName longName]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSArray*) sortedArray
{
    NSArray *arr1 = @[@{@"id":@1},@{@"id":@2},@{@"id":@3},@{@"id":@4}];
    NSArray *arr2 = @[@3,@1,@4,@2];

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSNumber *number in arr2)
    {
        for (NSDictionary* dictionary in arr1)
        {
            NSNumber *number2 = dictionary[@"id"];
            if ([number isEqual:number2])
            {
                [mutableArray addObject:dictionary];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return mutableArray;
}
```